# Как определить значение переменной?

Tags: алгоритм

Как определить, чему станет равно K в конце наших действий согласно алгоритму?

[image]

Comment: ответ 3

Comment: Объясните почему.

Comment: так как A<>B OR A<>C
мы пойдем по ветка "ДА"
Так как А>B+C
мы пойдем по ветка "ДА"
Потом А = 20
К увеличится на 1
Учись читать блок схемы

Comment: Речи нет тупанул не увидел что это цыкл

Comment: @ЫЫЫ Учитесь читать блок-схемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все  числа A, B, C станут равными 1. Просто повторяйте указанные действия, пока все значения  не сравняются. Получится так: (A,B,C) будет последовательно  равно

```
(25, 2, 3)->(20, 2, 3)->(15, 2, 3)->(10, 2, 3)-> (5, 2, 3)->(5, 1, 3)->(1, 1, 3)->(1, 1, 1),
```

после чего происходит переход на end.

С другими начальными данными этот алгоритм может выйти на отрицательные числа и зациклится (т.е. цикл не закончится).

Цикл повторится 8 раз, так что в конце k = 9

Answer (score 2):

7

```
(k, a, b, c) = (0, 25, 2, 3)
while a != b or a != c:
    if a > b + c:
        a = a - b - c
    elif a == b + c:
        b = c - b
    else:  c = c - a - b
    k = k + 1
print k, a, b, c
```